# I encountered a SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my Python code.

```
import time
question1 = input("What is 2+2: ")
if(question1 == "4"):
    print("Correct.")
    time.sleep(5)
else:
    print("Sorry " + question1 + " Is incorrect." )
    time.sleep(8)
```

This message pops up for a second when I run it then it just disappears but I managed to get a picture of it before it disappeared:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Comment: nothing wrong with your code as posted

Comment: Did you double-check special characters in your code?

Comment: Make sure you copy and paste it, so we get any typos you made too.

Comment: Also, try using raw input

Comment: It's python 3x there is no raw_input.Also I check your codes, it throws a _TypeError_ when open it with double-click to the file,otherwise no error. I just cant understand why.

Comment: Does this only occur when you give no input?

Comment: Does the script have a `.pyw` extention? How do you run it - double-clicking with your mouse in a window or on the command line?

Comment: Looks like you are actually running python 2.x.

Comment: chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67584/adding click please Portal 2 gLaDOS

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You push **ENTER** button without any answer so you got that error. I understand know. So before you push **ENTER** button, write an answer. I tried, and got same error because, without any answer just pushed to the **ENTER** in the **Console**.. In IDLE there is no problem.Your codes are not wrong, you just have to write an answer before pushing to *Enter* button.

> ***İmportant***: And this error only appears when you open the file with double-click. Try to open it in the same directory with console:

```
python filename.py
```

Dont open it with double-left click.

Comment: Put a comment for downvote please.Because I am very sure this is the answer of this question.

Comment: why can't I double click it? (I didn't downvote you btw)

Comment: I dont know, double-click sometimes throws errors like that. The best way for test is open your console at same directory where is your file, and _python filename.py_ run this codes

Comment: Could you pm me your skype? I would like to have you help me if I need more help later :/ Im kinda new

Comment: just click to that link I posted